# Telelgarm бот на библиотеке Aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Я пишу Telegram бот на библиотеке Aiogram. Пытаясь отправить сообщение возникает ошибка: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_task' line 83. Помогите решить проблему. Также я здесь использую заранее прописанный парсер и БД. Если надо, я могу скинуть парсер.

```
import config
import logging
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from sqlighter import SQLighter

from stopgame import StopGame # импортирую файл в котором прописан парсер с сайта "stopgame.ru" 

# задаем уровень логов
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# инициализируем бота
bot = Bot(token=config.API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# инициализируем соединение с БД
db = SQLighter('db.db')

# инициализируем парсер
sg = StopGame('lastkey.txt')

# Команда активации подписки
@dp.message_handler(commands=['subscribe'])
async def subscribe(message: types.Message):
    if(not db.subscriber_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        # если юзера нет в базе, добавляем его
        db.add_subscriber(message.from_user.id)
    else:
        # если он уже есть, то просто обновляем ему статус подписки
        db.update_subscription(message.from_user.id, True)
    
    await message.answer("Вы успешно подписались на рассылку!\nЖдите, скоро выйдут новые обзоры и вы узнаете о них ""первыми =)")


# Команда отписки
@dp.message_handler(commands=['unsubscribe'])
async def unsubscribe(message: types.Message):
    if(not db.subscriber_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        # если юзера нет в базе, добавляем его с неактивной подпиской (запоминаем)
        db.add_subscriber(message.from_user.id, False)
        await message.answer("Вы итак не подписаны.")
    else:
        # если он уже есть, то просто обновляем ему статус подписки
        db.update_subscription(message.from_user.id, False)
        await message.answer("Вы успешно отписаны от рассылки.")

# проверяем наличие новых игр и делаем рассылки
async def scheduled(wait_for):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(wait_for)

        # проверяем наличие новых игр
        new_games = sg.new_games()

        if(new_games):
            # если игры есть, переворачиваем список и итерируем
            new_games.reverse()
            for ng in new_games:
                # парсим инфу о новой игре
                nfo = sg.game_info(ng)

                # получаем список подписчиков бота
                subscriptions = db.get_subscriptions()

                # отправляем всем новость
                with open(sg.download_image(nfo['image']), 'rb') as photo:
                    for s in subscriptions:
                        await bot.send_photo(
                            s[1],
                            photo,
                            caption = nfo['title'] + "\n" + "Оценка: " + nfo['score'] + "\n" + nfo['excerpt'] + "\n\n" + nfo['link'],
                            disable_notification = True
                        )
                
                # обновляем ключ
                sg.update_lastkey(nfo['id'])

# запускаем лонг поллинг
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dp.loop.create_task(scheduled(10))
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Нужен стектрейс

Comment: как мне его реализовать в моем коде?

Comment: Его не нужно дополнительно реализовывать. Вы уже скопировали часть ошибки из стектрейса - `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_task' line 83.` Нужно в текст вопроса включить большую часть, чтоб увидеть в какой функции это случается, из какого места ее вызывали и т.д. Сейчас не ясно в каком месте кода ошибка, а стектрейс это показывает четко (если конечно вы также дадите привязку к номерам строк кода в примере, тут то они не отображаются)

Comment: Короче, вы можете исправить мой код, или нет?

Comment: В своих коментариях я просил включить больше информации о проблеме без которой помочь трудно, если вообще возможно. Грубить и хамить незнакомому человку, который вам пытается помочь не стоит. Если вы не понимаете о чем я прошу, то спросите, что непонятно.

Comment: Извините. Мне не понятно, как сделать  привязку к номерам строк в мое коде.

Comment: Про привязку строк имеется ввиду, что когда в ошибке указана строка типа так `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_task' line 83`, то я не знаю какая из строк кода в тексте вопроса является строкой номер 83 (не говоря о том, что тут даже не ясно в этом ли файле случилась ошибка). Это вы в редакторе можете посмотреть и написать тут.

Comment: Ошибка случилась в этом файле на предпоследней строке